# File upload in spring mvc

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc, file-upload

i have a file upload in my module and if gives me `true` always even if the file is not selected .

below is my code :

```
System.out.println("File Request : "+ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request));
        // Check that we have a file upload request
        if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            FilesInRequest.SaveFiles(request, request.getRealPath(""));
        }
```

what could be the wrong?

Please help me to find and fix this.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)` checks for only the request content type, if it starts with multipart `ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)` returns true.

One of the solution I used in the past was to check whether the request is of type `MultipartHttpServletRequest` and get the `fileMap` to see whether files exists.

```
Map<String, MultipartFile> fileMap = new HashMap<String, MultipartFile>();
if (request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest) {
    MultipartHttpServletRequest multiRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
    fileMap = multiRequest.getFileMap();
}
if(fileMap.size() > 0 ) {
}
```

I don't know How optimal this is.

Comment: So what is the solution for this ??